# Very slow perform_later call on ActiveJob and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a `SchedulerJob`:

```
class SchedulerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :scheduler

  def perform
    logger.debug("Start")
    DelayedJob.set(wait: 10.seconds).perform_later
    logger.debug("After Job 1")
    DelayedJob.set(wait: 20.seconds).perform_later
    logger.debug("After Job 2")
    DelayedJob.set(wait: 30.seconds).perform_later
    logger.debug("End")
  end
end
```

and a `DelayedJob`:

```
class DelayedJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :delayed_jobs

  def perform
    puts "I'm done"
  end
end
```

If I call `SchedulerJob.new.perform` the job runs in just a few milliseconds. If I call `SchedulerJob.perform_later` to run the job in Sidekiq it takes about 90 seconds to finish, and by looking at the logs I can tell that each of those `.perform_later` calls takes about 30 seconds each.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

1. `perform_later` will be performed as soon as queuing system is free
2. `perform` will be performed regardless of your queue status

My guess is that when you call `perform_later`, there are some jobs running in the queue.

Comment: That would just mean the job would take longer to execute, but it doesn't affect how long it takes to be enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the initializer. [This was the solution:](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3837)

> My guess is you’ve destroyed all concurrency by hacking in one global $REDIS connection into the pool. Don’t do that. Let Sidekiq create and manage the pool of connections.